# How do i get the member count of a discord server with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How do I code my discord bot to find the amount of members in a discord server and store it as a variable.
Secondly how do i code my discord bot to delete other peoples messages when a certain event (e.g if the message contains a vulgar word) thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get the membercount of the server, the `.memberCount` property will work

```
let membercount = message.guild.memberCount
```

For deleting swear words,

```
if (message.toLowerCase().includes(`poop`) {
  message.delete()
  message.channel.send(`poop is a swear word`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one:

```js
let members = message.guild.members;
```

For the second one, you should use a RegEx:

```js
if (message.content.match(/SwearWord/)) message.delete({ reason: "Swearword" });
```

You just need to adjust the swearword RegEx. Also, note for next time: please provide some more info like some code showing what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

to get member count in a guild you have to get the `memberCount` property from the `Guild`. \n
example -

```js
const memberCount = message.guild.memberCount
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`memberCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount) property of a `Guild` to find how many members it has.
[image]

---

To detect swear words, you can use the `includes()` function. Example of how the `.includes()` function works:

```js
// example message
const message = 'Hello World!'

if (message.includes('Hello'))
  console.log('This message includes the word hello');
```

If the first string includes the second given string, this function will return `true`. Otherwise, it will return `false`. This in itself will work fine if you only have *one* swear word to detect, but there is a more efficient method if there are multiple.

```js
// another example message
const message = 'My name is John. I like baking, dancing, and playing Mario.';

// now, create an array of every swear word you'd like to avoid
// make sure they're in lower case!
const array = ['baking', 'dancing', 'playing'];

var foundInText = false;

// here's the fun part. create a loop iterating through every element in your
// blacklisted word array

for (word of array) {
  // if one of the words is included in the message,
  // flip the `foundInText` variable to true!
  if (message.toLowerCase().includes(word)) {
  foundInText = true;
  break; // break out of the loop, a word was found
  };
};

// if a word was found...
if (foundInText) {
  // you can do whatever you want here
  // including deleting the message,
  // sending a warning...
  // whatever you want
  console.log('This string has a blacklisted word');
};
```